# Getting a list of files from several folders in one request using Google Drive REST API

Tags: c#, google-drive-api, google-apis-explorer

I'm trying to get metadata for all files in a particular publicly shared Google Drive folder using the v3/drive.files.list API. My current approach is to first get a list of everything in root,

```
q='some-id' in parents
```

and then repeat similar queries for all the subdirectiories found. What I'd like to do instead of requesting data for each subdirectory individually is to combine queries like so:

```
q='some-subdir-id-1' in parents or 'some-dubdir-id-2' in parents
```

(edited: originally posted query with `and` by mistake)

However, in APIs explorer this (sometimes) returns only files in one of directories, and in .NET binding it simply returns an empty list with no exceptions being thrown. So, is there a way to have multiple `'something' in parents` parameters in a single query?

[Test case.](https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/drive/v3/drive.files.list?pageSize=10&q='1veu5IIIo64Hp0tMGnvckvs0w3f3vKOo4'+in+parents+or+'1V8VB5iAQWxxjaVC1UJoz6QNDsFTcEpR0'+in+parents&spaces=drive&_h=17&)

Answer (score 1):

You want to retrieve all files in several folders by one query. If my understanding is correct, how about this query?

```
q='some-subdir-id-1' in parents or 'some-dubdir-id-2' in parents or 'some-dubdir-id-3' in parents
```

#### Note :

- At above query, using `or`, the files in the folders of `some-subdir-id-1`, `some-subdir-id-2` and `some-subdir-id-3` are retrieved.
- When `parents` is used for `fields`, you can also retrieve the parents for each file, simultaneously.

#### Reference :

- [Search for Files](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/search-parameters)

If this was not what you want, I'm sorry.

Comment: Your understanding is correct, however, the solution does not work for me. I've tried this in an [APIs explorer](https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/drive/v3/drive.files.list) and got an empty files list, same with C# code. If requested for just one parent, it works as expected~

Comment: @Jade I'm sorry for the inconvenience. I noticed my mistake point in my answer. I updated my answer. Please confirm it. I tried this query at APIs explorer again. In my environment, all files in each folder can be retrieved. And if you use this, the query parameter is required to be done URL encode.

Comment: Have you tested it on folders you own or have unlimited access to? My questing is specifically about folders that are not mine, but are public, like `1veu5IIIo64Hp0tMGnvckvs0w3f3vKOo4` and `1V8VB5iAQWxxjaVC1UJoz6QNDsFTcEpR0`. I've tried a request like the one you've provided, and it does work, but only when authorized as owner of both the folders. Otherwise I get an empty list.

Comment: @Jade I'm really sorry. I could notice that I had misunderstood your question. I couldn't find the query for retrieving the files in the both parents. I'm sorry. As a workaround, if you want to retrieve the files in the both parents by one API call, how about use of [Batching Requests](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/batch)? This can be retrieve files in several parents by one API call.